# Multiple MX record priority

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, godaddy

My domain MX records points to my webserver Ip address, while GoDaddy tutorial suggest to use an MX record that points to my smtp server ip address.

I think that one server point to the other one.

Which server should be used as the mx record with the highest priority ?

Answer (score 1):

First, just to be sure: The highest priority is the one with the lowest preference value.

Second: Naturally, the first contact for your mail (hightest priority) needs to be your actual mail server, not the web server. Also, you should only list the web server at all as an MX if it is configured to actually handle incoming mail in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

The MX record should "point" to whichever server handles email for your domain.